# How to resume Audio using Mpmusicplayer after pause audio in swift 4.1(IOS 11)

Tags: ios, mpmusicplayercontroller, swift4.1

I am working on Audio playing app using "MpmusicPlayer" and want to resume it after paused.

I am using "self.appMusicPlayer.currentPlaybackTime" but it is not working in swift 4.1 (IOS 11).

Is there have any other way to resume audio after pause using MpMusicPlayer?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this is a problem with iOS 11 that some people have run into when setting the `currentPlaybackTime` after calling `play()`. There was a work around posted on this [apple dev forum here,](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/85602) but please find the code below (thanks to RunLoop).

> I had just run into this exact problem. I managed to get around it
>   with the following code.
>
> It creates a background thread that continuously checks the
>   `currentPlaybackTime` of the player. As soon as `currentPlaybackTime`
>   is not the time I set it to be I set `currentPlaybackTime` back to
>   what I wanted.
>
> It feels like a terrible hack but it's working for me so far.

```
MPMusicPlayerController *player = [MPMusicPlayerController systemMusicPlayer];  
player.currentPlaybackTime = _startTime;  
[player play];  

dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0ul);  
dispatch_async(queue, ^{  
  while(true) {  
    if (player.currentPlaybackTime != _startTime) {  
      player.currentPlaybackTime = _startTime;  
      break;  
    }  
  }  
});
```

Comment: @GalaxyPatel I've edited my answer with another code example

Comment: thanks for your reply but this second one also not working for me because MPMusicPlayer always play music from start position and  after it DispatchQueue is called.
And I change value of  currentPlaybackTime  but MpMusicPlayer start playing music from 0.0 always.